# consuming service reference typescript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, service-reference

How to consume service reference in Typescript HTML App using Visual Studio   2013.
I have added a service reference to my typescript HTML app. but don't know  how  to call service client in typescript code.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript HTML App template in VS 2013 uses C# project type as wrapper. That means you can add Service Reference in UI. But there is no built in support to consume such reference in TypeScript - there is no service client unless you implement it.